# iTunes crashing when trying to sign in

Tags: wine

I'm running Itunes 12.9.3 in wine, followed directions here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SVgGX9x1hWZzyhEJs5_7UH1K5i7Cuz6B2iuIwm40VrQ/edit

Every time I try to sign in, iTunes crashes. log: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/176y3NCZwsZEIu2BtKZUAabnrn19YhDcm/view?usp=sharing)

Will someone please help me to a working solution?

linux Mint Cinnamon 19.2